# Entity framework composite foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, composite-key

I have the following setup

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public JobVersion JobVersion { get; set; }
}

public class JobVersion
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

I want JobVersion.JobId to be a foreign key to Job.Id.
JobVersion.JobId and JobVersion.Version should be a composite key, so that Version increments for every 'group' of JobId
If Job.CurrentVersion is not null the JobVersion navigation property should work.

Im trying to create a JobVersion history table, so that only one JobVersion per Job can be active. So if CurrentVersion is changed, the current JobVersion is changed.

I think i have tried all FluentApi setups i can think of, but cant get it to work. Is it possible?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Try temporal tables. This is not something EF can do for you out of the box.